# Angular.js: how to get rendered text width from directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

I need to (dynamically) render text inside fixed-length buttons in a *ng-repeat* block.
I would like to get DOM rendered text width (to be able to truncate it, and add an ellipsis entity...).
This is my html:

```
 <span ng-repeat="(key, item) in players" limit-text-length max-len="100">
    <div class="btn">
      <div id="player-{{key}}">{{item.name}}</div>
    </div>
 </span>
```

This is my current directive:

```
app.directive('limitTextLength', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
  var maxLen = attrs.maxLen;
  var el = element.find​("[id^=player-]"); // <-- THIS DOESN'T WORK...
  if (el.width() > maxLen) { // check text is not too wide
    while (el.width() > maxLen) {
      var nameTruncated = el.html();
      nameTruncated = nameTruncated.substring(0, nameTruncated.length - 1);
      el.html(nameTruncated);
    }
    el.append('&hellip;');
  }
};
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe you could try to put `var el = element.find​("[id^=player-]"); [...]` inside `$timeout()` function. Then it should be run after text render.

Comment: @ExpertSystem's answer should solve this but did you consider edge case where adding ellipsis would change the width and make it more than maxLen?

Comment: @czwek: yes, this is the right solution... See ExpertSystem answer...

Comment: @amitamb: yes, maxLen should take into account the ellipsis width...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`element.find("[id^=player-]")` won't work without jQuery, because Angular's jqLite's `find()` is *limited to lookups by tag name* (according to **[the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)**).

You could use the native `querySelector()` method, which has **[good support in browsers](http://caniuse.com/queryselector)**:

```
//var el = element.find("[id^=player-]");
var el = angular.element(element[0].querySelector('[id^="player-"'));
```

<sub>Of course, without jQuery the `.width()` method won't be available, but if you do use jQuery, your selector should work fine.</sub>

---

There is also a typo: `var maxLen = attrs.len;` should be `var maxLen = attrs.maxLen;`

---

That said, the main problem is that the element's actual width is determined **after** being rendered (which hasn't happened at the time you check). You could make sure you check after the element has been rendered, by wrapping the relevant code inside `$timeout`.
Your directive could be modified like this (assuming jQuery is included):

```
app.directive('limitTextLength', function ($timeout) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var maxLen = attrs.maxLen;
        var el = element.find("[id^=player-]");
        $timeout(function () {
            if (el.width() > maxLen) { // check text is not too wide
                while (el.width() > maxLen) {
                    console.log(el.width());
                    var nameTruncated = el.html();
                    nameTruncated = nameTruncated.substring(0, nameTruncated.length - 1);
                    el.html(nameTruncated);
                }
                el.append('&hellip;');
            }
        });
    };
});
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/b9H5n/)**.

---

BTW, if it is just for the ellipsis, you could use CSS3's **[`text-overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)** property.

Comment: This is a perfect answer.
I knew element find needs a full jQuery; I could obtain the same result using jqLite alternatives, but I did not mention it in the answer because it's not as straightforward as jQuery... My compliments for noticing it.
I did suppose the problem was with rendering not completed when directive executes. My compliments for solving it.
I didn't think about text-overflow, but my main goal was to gain experience with Angular directives...
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Just for future reference: I had a minor issue with my html: I had to use a span instead of a div (`<span id="player-{{key}}">{{item.name}}</span>`), otherwise width was related to the text container, instead of text itself...

Comment: @MarcoS: I have replaced it with a `<span>` in my demo, but I assumed you were applying some CSS to the same end in your code. If not, then indeed a `<div>` will never change it's size based on text-content (and it will eventually crash your browser (because of the infinite `while` loop).